# C# Regex - Equivalent for "\g" in regex101.com?

Tags: c#, regex

I plan to use a regex I have constructed a regex over at regex101.com into a C# application:

```
((?'d'(?:3[0-9]\s+)){2})2f\s+(\g'd'{2})2f\s+(\g'd'{4})
```

The problem is that C# complains that:

```
Unrecognized escape sequence \g.
```

What is the equivalent syntax for "\g" in C# regex? Or is there a better alternative for the regex that I plan to use?

Link to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/CP4ZS0/1

Comment: There is no support for recursion in .net regexes. But in this case you could simply roll out the full pattern, replacing the recursion with the recursed pattern.

Comment: Just repeat the subpattern. .NET regex does not support `\g'n'` recursion construct.

Comment: @SebastianProske Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @SebastianProske, Wiktor Stribiżew - Thanks a lot, I just had to replace the named group with the pattern it self. It now works.

Comment: @slimjourney You may build the pattern dynamically. `var p = @"(?:3[0-9]\s+)";` and then `var rx=$@"{p}{{2}}2f\s+{p}{{2}}2f\s+{p}{{4}}";`. That is, if you need to make the code shorter. However, it is just the same as Sebastian's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for recursion in .net RegEx. Just apply the recursed pattern where you use the recursion, like

```
(?:3[0-9]\s+){2}2f\s+(?:3[0-9]\s+){2}2f\s+(?:3[0-9]\s+){4}
```

I have removed all the capturing groups, you might want to reapply them where you need.

See https://regex101.com/r/CP4ZS0/2

Comment: Is there any documentation of that `\g` construct? I only saw (?R) for recursion.

Comment: @Evk See https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC21 - it is mentioned (but it's also the first time I see that construct in the wild)

Comment: yes i found following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions